# What exactly means "epistemological" here?

Tags: meaning

I have a hard time describing the meaning of the word epistemological, and thus the proper meaning of the quote, in my own words. I do get the big message but I'd love to be able to answer the question "What does epistemological mean?" if someone would ask me.

> «[It] may be said of all the debates in the foundation of mathematics:
>   either they are technical and accessible only to logicians, or they
>   are epistomological and draw their examples from concepts we meet in
>   school. The result in each case is a debate that does not interest,
>   and does not seek to affect, working mathematicians.»

**Definition of epistemological**

: of, relating to, or based on epistemology : relating to the study of the nature, origin, and limits of human knowledge

Comment: Can you begin by providing a dictionary definition?

Comment: I think you mean "epist**e**mological".

Comment: @HotLicks I thought about using "epistemolgical" and it would be the correct term but my source actually uses "epistomological". Might be a typo but I didn't want to change the quote from how it is presented in my source.

Comment: Basically epistemological questions have to do what sorts of things are knowable, as opposed to ontological questions which have to do with what sorts of things exist.

Comment: Dictionaries can send you round in circles: here is another [definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/epistemological). If the author of the quote does not know how to spell it, maybe does not know its meaning either, and (as some do) throws it in for effect.

Comment: Epistemology is a pre-research course taught to PhD aspirants. It is the study of knowledge acquired by human beings. Doctorates/ researchers can tell more about it.